# TinyMCE bar always on top

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

I need to lock the toolbar for a TinyMCE text field so that it always appears at the top of the page even as the text field gets larger and the page scrolls.

Is there a way to put this in a separate  element so this can be done?

I've searched this forum and others without much luck.

Comment: Any Luck? I am looking for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
#content_toolbar1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

depending on you amount of toolbar's and id's ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

Parse TinyMCE on special div like this:

```
<div id="TinyMCEContainer">
 <!-- TinyMCE Code -->
</div> 
<div id="RestOfHtml">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#TinyMCEContainer
{
  position: absolute; // or fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px; // You height
}
#RestOfHtml
{
 margin-top: 200px; // You height
}
```